# Why does my error handler doesn't work in asp net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, error-handling

I'm using a global error handler in ASP.NET Core 7.0:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    
        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
    
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    
                var error = new ErrorDto
                {
                    Code = context.Response.StatusCode,
                    Description = "badReq"
                };
    
                var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
            }
        }
}
```

and register it in my `Program.cs`:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
```

I would like to handle several http request errors in my handler, how to do this. Because if I throw a single custom exception at the moment an error occurs, it works as it should. How to handle multiple errors (including `HttpStatusCode`)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by handling several request errors? If you just want to handle exceptions, you may also want to consider using `app.UseExceptionHandler` as an alternative: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

For better handling of various HTTP request errors in your ASP.NET 7.0 app with your existing ErrorHandlingMiddleware, consider tweaking the catch block to individually tackle different exceptions. Right now, your middleware catches and processes all exceptions in the same manner, which isn't always suitable for different error types.

In this version, CustomExceptionTypeA and CustomExceptionTypeB are just examples. Replace them with the actual exception types relevant to your application. The WriteErrorResponse method is designed to streamline error response creation.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (CustomExceptionTypeA ex)
    {
        // Handling specific for CustomExceptionTypeA
        await WriteErrorResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error A occurred");
    }
    catch (CustomExceptionTypeB ex)
    {
        // Handling specific for CustomExceptionTypeB
        await WriteErrorResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error B occurred");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handling for general exceptions
        await WriteErrorResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "General error occurred");
    }
}

private async Task WriteErrorResponse(HttpContext context, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;

    var error = new ErrorDto
    {
        Code = context.Response.StatusCode,
        Description = message
    };

    var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
}
```

For instance:

```
   catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        // Handle the case when a file is not found
        await WriteErrorResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not found");
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        // Handle the case when a user is not authorized to access a resource
        await WriteErrorResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized access");
    }
```

Comment: i tried your example, i have an error 404, but the responce is catch (Exception ex)         {             await WriteErrorResponse(context, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "General error occurred");         }

Comment: It looks like the middleware isn't catching the FileNotFoundException as it should, and is defaulting to the general exception handler instead. a few reasons: 

1-The Right Exception Might Not Be Thrown: The error you're trying to catch may not actually be a FileNotFoundException

2- Check the Order of Middleware

3- Look for Exception Handling Elsewhere

4- Routing Related Issues: If the 404 error is due to a URL that doesn't match any routes (like a non-existent page), it might not throw a FileNotFoundException, but the framework itself might return a 404 response.

Comment: @WinterWind Can you send me the result please?